# Resetting previously selected folder when selecting a file with Finder

Tags: finder, preferences, defaults

I use a personal password manager and the database is protected by a password and you have to provide a key file. To select the key file you click a file selection dropdown. A Finder window pops up and opens the folder I previously navigated to with this file dropdown and presents you the folder where I stored the key file. In terms of security, you understand this is not desirable behaviour.

Ideally I would want Finder to just open the default folder that pops up when I open a new Finder window. I would like to modify this behaviour for this specific application, but a system wide solution is also welcome. I don't mind clicking through several folders.

I am on a relatively fresh install of MacOS High Sierra 10.13.4 and I'm not afraid of tinkering with the Terminal or AppleScript. I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, my question was not so popular that it inspired people to answer my question. But after rephrasing my google search terms and some investigation of my own. I found a solution to this.

It appears every application stores these previously opened folders as `defaults`, which is also the command you need in Terminal to see and reset this value.

I stumbled upon [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-delete-a-recently-opened-file-history-on-a-Mac#__w2_uxshRZV_answers_anchor) which introduced me to the `defaults` command. It seems all you need is the bundle identifier of your application (in the source example `org.videolan.vlc`) and the namespace of the default you are trying to erase.

I found the bundle identifier of my application by typing `lsof | grep [appname]` 
 (which isn't very reliable, because the application name could differ slightly from the bundle identifier) and looking for `Library` (which commonly hold folder names with these bundle identifiers) in the result. But you can also do `defaults read > defaults.log` and search the file for your the path of the folder you are trying to erase the default for.

This led me to the namespace `NSNavLastRootDirectory`. So all I have to do is execute the command `defaults delete com.bundle.identifier NSNavLastRootDirectory` everytime right before I open the application.

How I am going to do that? I'm not sure yet. Probably some Applescript solution.
Furthermore I was wondering if I used the right tags for this, since my question got so little attention.